# Расположить несколько блоков по горизонтали

Tags: html, css

Допустим есть родитель с четырьмя блоками внутри.
Родитель и блоки внутри должны быть размером с ширину экрана и расположены по горизонтали.
Причём так, чтобы первый блок был виден, а остальные были вне экрана (справа).

В голову пришла только такая реализация, но я прям чую где-то подвох + самому не нравится реализация.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.list {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #999;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100%;
  right: -100%;
  background: #666;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  left: 200%;
  right: -200%;
  background: #333;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  left: 300%;
  right: -300%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

P.s. Без `flex`ов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я на css очень мало пишу, но могу предложить упрощенный вариант:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.list {
  width: 400vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: #999;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background: #666;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: #333;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Эх, без flexов бы)

Comment: Не так тяжело переделать, сделал

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 то мой ответ подходит?

Comment: Да, укажу как правильный, других всё равно нет)